# Text breaking table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a table, and as you can see, it has two rows. Ignore the @ and {{ }} codes. They are just templating engine stuff. My problem is that, whenever I place large text instead of `{{ $tournament->tournamentDescription }}`, it really expands my entire table, and goes out of the bootstrap `col-md-8` and overlaps the `col-md-4` after it. I tried adding this class:

```
.nested-item {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ucbmk79v/

But it didn't seem to work. This is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
            <h1>Tournaments Listing</h1>
            <table id="tournamentlist" class="display" style="max-width:100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Tournament Name </th>
                <th>Creator</th>
                <th>Number of Players</th>
                <th>Number of Players</th>
                <th>Entrance Fee</th>
                <th>Game</th>
                <th>Platform</th>
                <th>Entry Type</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Tournament Name </th>
                <th>Creator</th>
                <th>Number of Players</th>
                <th>Number of Players</th>
                <th>Entrance Fee</th>
                <th>Game</th>
                <th>Platform</th>
                <th>Entry Type</th>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($options['tournaments'] as $tournament)
            <tr role="row">
                <td class="details-control"></td>
                <td><a href="{{ $websiteURL }}/tournaments/{{ $tournament->id }}">{{ $tournament->tournamentName }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="{{ $websiteURL }}/tournaments/{{ $tournament->id }}">{{ $tournament->creator }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="{{ $websiteURL }}/tournaments/{{ $tournament->id }}">{{$tournament->playercount}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="{{ $websiteURL }}/tournaments/{{ $tournament->id }}">{{ $tournament->noOfParticipants }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="{{ $websiteURL }}/tournaments/{{ $tournament->id }}">{{ $tournament->entranceFee }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="{{ $websiteURL }}/tournaments/{{ $tournament->id }}">{{ $tournament->game }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="{{ $websiteURL }}/tournaments/{{ $tournament->id }}">{{ $tournament->gamePlatform }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="{{ $websiteURL }}/tournaments/{{ $tournament->id }}">{{ $tournament->teamType }}</a></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="9">
                    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="col-md-8">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="nested-item">
                                <td>Description:</td>
                                <td>{{ $tournament->tournamentDescription }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`word-wrap: break-word` is not enough. Use `word-break: break-all` to ensure the word-wrap actually *is* executed also on long or odd "non-breakable" strings :

```css
table tbody td {
   white-space: normal;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   word-break: break-all; 
}
```

The demo:

```css
table tbody td {
   white-space: normal;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   word-break: break-all; 
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1>Tournaments Listing</h1>
            <table id="tournamentlist" class="display" style="max-width:100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Tournament Name </th>
                <th>Creator</th>
                <th>Number of Players</th>
                <th>Number of Players</th>
                <th>Entrance Fee</th>
                <th>Game</th>
                <th>Platform</th>
                <th>Entry Type</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Tournament Name </th>
                <th>Creator</th>
                <th>Number of Players</th>
                <th>Number of Players</th>
                <th>Entrance Fee</th>
                <th>Game</th>
                <th>Platform</th>
                <th>Entry Type</th>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($options['tournaments'] as $tournament)
            <tr role="row">
                <td class="details-control"></td>
                <td><a href="{{ $websiteURL }}/tournaments/{{ $tournament->id }}">{{ $tournament->tournamentName }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="{{ $websiteURL }}/tournaments/{{ $tournament->id }}">{{ $tournament->creator }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="{{ $websiteURL }}/tournaments/{{ $tournament->id }}">{{$tournament->playercount}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="{{ $websiteURL }}/tournaments/{{ $tournament->id }}">{{ $tournament->noOfParticipants }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="{{ $websiteURL }}/tournaments/{{ $tournament->id }}">{{ $tournament->entranceFee }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="{{ $websiteURL }}/tournaments/{{ $tournament->id }}">{{ $tournament->game }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="{{ $websiteURL }}/tournaments/{{ $tournament->id }}">{{ $tournament->gamePlatform }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="{{ $websiteURL }}/tournaments/{{ $tournament->id }}">{{ $tournament->teamType }}</a></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="9">
                    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="col-md-8">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="nested-item">
                                <td>Description:</td>
                                <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
            </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    Hi
  </div>
</div>
```

updated fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ucbmk79v/4/**

Comment: Browser support reference here: [word-break](http://caniuse.com/#feat=word-break)